# Unit test saving/retrieving object

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Haven't really used much unit testing before, but read up on it a bit and got the idea that you really only should test 1 thing at a time. But how to do this in a nice way when for example saving and retrieving an object? I can't see that the save worked without using the "retrieve" function. And can't test the retrieve without saving something. At the moment I tried something like this... How can I assure that my test can know which one is not working?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSaveObject()
    {
        TestStorage storage = new TestStorage();
        ObejctToSave s1 = new ObejctToSave {Name = "TEST1"};
        ObejctToSave s2 = new ObejctToSave { Name = "TEST2" };
        storage.SaveObject(s1);
        storage.SaveObject(s2);
        List<ObjectToSave> objects = storage.GetObjects();
        Assert.AreEqual(2, objects.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("TEST1", objects[0].Name);
        Assert.AreEqual("TEST2", objects[1].Name);
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this an integration test?

Comment: @Mitch I'm testing an Interface that saves/retrieves the object (for example a database)

Comment: @David I don't really know, is it? As i said I'm new to this and like to get the hang of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You noted yourself that unit-tests ought to test one thing at a time. And yet here you're testing two things - storage and retrieval.

If you want to test your service layer for handling persistence correctly, mock the persistence object (repository), and then call service methods to add object - verifying that appropriate methods on repository were called. The same for retrieval.

The main issue is whether:

- you are implementing a persistence library. If yes, you should of course test peristence methods, using mock objects that will fake OS calls to file system operations.
- you want to test your persistence methods (as your example suggests), but they are using 3rd party library. It doesn't make sense for [unit-tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) - this is the part when [integration testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) plays its role.

Briefly speaking - unit test tests a single unit - a "module" of your code separately from other modules. Other parts are being [mocked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) for the purpose of verifying only the code of the unit being tested.

Integration test on the other hand tests a group of modules working together. Often integration tests are implemented to tests typical use cases of your whole system, sometimes they are used for regression testing of only a group of modules for example. There are many possibilities, but the point is that modules are being tested working together - hence *integration*.

Comment: I know this is not the way to do it, thats why I ask how it could be done instead... What is the difference between unit test and integration testing?

Comment: @Nick3 I don't what "it" is, so can't provide you an alternative. What is it that you want to test exactly? I've added more explanation to the answer. You don't test databases - they are being tested by developers of these databases. Unit tests are usually for your code.

Comment: I'm not really sure myself, in this case I like to see that my save acts like it supposed to, I would like to get the same thing out the 'getObjects' as I put in with 'SaveObject'. Since I'm new to the testing I don't know much about how to do this (what kind of tests and so on), do you have an example how I can make this happen in any way that is a good practice that would be great.

Comment: @Nick3 Well yes, the thing you describe is a simple integration test, good one to have a the beginning of a project (later most tests will store or something along with their scenario). On this level of generality your example looks fine. For integration testing usually you have a database snapshot (for example in a XML file) you load it, act on it, and verify results.

Comment: Ok, great. I will look into that, but if this is fine at this point I will go with it! As I said, just trying to get going!

Answer (score 1):

I like the Idea to test one function by using it-s inverse-function
 even if this means testing two things at a time and this is probably an integrationtest and not a unittest.

However there are some problems i experienced doing this.

- **sort order** of lists **false negative**: In your example `storage.GetObjects()` might retrieve the ojects in the wrong order so your test might fail although every single object was handled correctly. The same applies for objects with sub-lists.
- **maintaining this test**: if you add new properties to `ObejctToSave` and forget to update the corresponding test you get a **false positive** - `ObejctToSave` tells you success althoug the new property is not persisted properly.

For a workaround for these limitations in dotnet i did this

- using [nbuilder](http://code.google.com/p/nbuilder/) library that automatically assigns a reproducable value to each property so new properties are automatically tested
- created a custom object-compare method `compare<t>(t object1, t object2, params string[] propertyNamesToBeIgnoredInTest)` that uses reflection to compare the properties and sorts sub-list before comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting point. I think to do it in the most proper TDD way ( that wouldn't be necessary the way it should ) is to create a TestStorage mock, and assert the proper calls are satisfied on it. So you can create a separate test for the Save an Retrieve, both with the mock and proper expectations on it.

Comment: Do you have any example how the things I'm tring to test can be done like that?

Comment: try to lock at some mocking libraries doc, for example: https://github.com/Moq/moq4